# How to write a single query statement with multiple foreign keys in codeigniter in best way

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

The scenario is quite simple. I have a table called "companies" from which I want to fetch data for a company. there are foreign keys for - "industry", "company_sizes", "ownership_type", "user". I am looking for the best way to fetch the data either using a raw query or query builder so that it uses minimal server resources and get data asap.

I am using CodeIgniter 3.

table columns which I want to fetch

[image]

Query which I used is below:

```
$this->db->select('a.*, b.user_name, c.industry_type, d.ownership_type, e.company_size');
$this->db->from('companies a');
$this->db->where('a.id', $company_id);
$this->db->join('users b', 'a.user_id = b.user_id');
$this->db->join('industry c', 'a.industry_id = c.id');
$this->db->join('ownership d', 'a.ownership_type_id = d.id');
$this->db->join('company_sizes e', 'a.company_size_id = e.id');
$this->db->get()->row();
```

But, I know that a.* will fetch and show only the foreign ids mentioned above, but i want the actual responses from those table in place of them. If anyone have a better solution for multiple tables, please let me know.

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking or what the problem is.  "*... only the foreign ids ...  i want the actual responses from those table ...*" So let's take the `industry` table, `a.*` will show you `a.industry_id`, but you're also selecting `c.industry_type`, which should be the corresponding text/value from that table?  What is the problem?